# Wordpress 3.2 query_posts and pagination, permalinks issue

Tags: php, query, pagination

My question is not new but it just does not work with all found solutions in my case.

I am trying to display recent posts on single post using custom query_posts loop. The permalinks structure must be this one: /%category%/%postname%/

Wordpress version: 3.2.1

The page has 2 loops:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!--first content part-->
<?php endwhile; endif;?>

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged='.$paged);

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!--recent posts-->
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

So calling next page like http://www.domain.com/category/post-one/page/2/
simply strips off /page/2/ and does nothing else.

I am desperate already for looking a working solution and not sure if its possible to fix.

Thank you.

Comment: Test with one of the provided permalink structures(just not default or custom), eg. Day and Name, if that resolves the issue you know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

From the WP Codex for WP_Query:

> **Show Posts from Current Page**
>
> **Display posts from current page:**
>
> $query = new WP_Query( 'paged=' . get_query_var( 'page' ) );
>
> **Pagination Note:** You should set get_query_var( 'page' ); if you want your query to work with pagination. Since Wordpress 3.0.2, you do get_query_var( 'page' ) instead of get_query_var( 'paged' ). The pagination parameter 'paged' for WP_Query() remains the same.

Changing the query var from 'paged' to 'page' will result in the following code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!--first content part-->
<?php endwhile; endif;?>

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged='.$paged);

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <!--recent posts-->
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: Just tried your solution but no luck. It does not work and still strips off /page/2/ remaining on the same page. Maybe your solution works for default permalink structure or just index page. But my case it does not resolve :(((( any idea what could i try else. It seems so simple the idea... just to display recent posts with pagination on single post template.

Comment: Perhaps the page query var is protected.  Try passing your own variable such as mypage.  To use mypage you will need to use add_filter to add a query var and a rewrite rule.  [WP_Rewrite Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite) will give you more information on rewrite and has an example to do what I just mentioned.

Comment: I think that note is incorrect, @scribu [introduced that note](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Class_Reference/WP_Query&oldid=101572) on the codex entry, but i think it's actually incorrect, `page` and `paged` have different meaning, `paged` refers to pagination for archives, where as `page` refers to the pages of a single entry(a multiple page post for example - eg. when you use `<!--nextpage-->`). Perhaps scribu misinterpreted it's usage, or perhaps i'm even misunderstanding the usage myself.

Comment: Very sad that there is no really clear explanation about that. Anyway, page or paged still did not work. I would try what @scribu said but i am not very programming savvy and doubt i would get the correct piece of code for my example. Maybe someone could get a hand on that solution.